# Where does the API call from the interactive card in Google Chat go?

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api, google-chat

I am trying to replicate examples from the Google Docs about [Creating interactive cards in Google Chat](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick?authuser=0). I have created a sample link in my card.

[Sample card with a link "click me"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7aKP.png)

But once I hit "click me" I have no idea where the request goes and how to steer that it's routed to my publicly available Node.js express route on Google Cloud run.

I must have missed something about the basic bot communication. Can you help me? (Background. I am sending my card via a simple webhook at this point.)

Comment: Is this built in Apps Script?

Comment: No, this is a Node.js app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out, that my implementation was not suitable for interactive cards. If someone clicks an interactive card Google Chat will notify the creating bot at its API point specified in the Google Cloud configuration.

So posting the card via WebHook is possible. But there is not communication channel back in this scenario.

I resolved my issue by implementing it with a proper Google Chat bot.